# How to import a class from a .py file which is in a subdirectory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder as follows:

[image: Folder structure]

The `message.py` file has a class `Message` that I would like to import and similarly `segments.py` file has a class `Segment` that I would like to import.

When I do:

```
from pydifact.message import Message
from pydifact.segments import Segment
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-cc598c8ad3ca>", line 1, in <module>
    from pydifact.message import Message

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydifact.message'
```

But when I add:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, r"C:\Users\Desktop\automatic-mscons-invoice-generator\edilite\pydifact")

from pydifact.message import Message
from pydifact.segments import Segment
```

it works fine.

Is there a way I can do the imports directly without having to add the `sys.path.insert` ?

My working directory is:

`C:\Users\Desktop\automatic-mscons-invoice-generator`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3)

Comment: It depends from your IDE, for example PyCharm manages it.

Comment: There are 2 nested directories named 'pydifact' !

Comment: @MauriceMeyer is right, you could a **"\pydifact"** at the end of your path. Afterward get the rid of the **"pydifact"** at the beggining of each of your **imports**. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, adding to `sys.path` manually solved the problem.

Try adding that path to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, this tells the interpreter where are the scripts available for `import`ing.